# jQuery Ajax not updating textarea

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

SO this is suposed to detect when my slect drop-down menu in the form changes, make an ajax call and change the contents of a textarea to the returned data from the AJAX call. After tests it all works except it seems to refuse to return the contents of the ajax call.

Heres the jQuery:

```
$("select#vars").change(function(){
    var name = $("select#vars").val();
    $.ajax({
        url:"sys/get_var.php?name=" + encodeURIComponent(name),  
        success:function(datas) {
            $("textarea#var_value").val(datas);
        }
    });
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: try console.log(datas) and see in browser developer tool what data it is returning..

Comment: bind error callback and check response error and use your network tab in console

Comment: Posting your html may help a bit more. And do you actually see the value when you access the url directly via the browser with a hard coded name value?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the data to be returned then use the dataType: 'json'.

Check out the following piece of code does this :-

```
$.ajax({
    url     : 'your_url_path',
    type    : 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    data    : {name1:name},//left side 'name1' is used to access the value like $_GET['name1'] 
    success : function(retuObj){ 
        //on success your code
    }
});
```